# Django efficient Queryset with Foreign Key Models

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to find the most efficient way (as less db queries as possible) for the following model structure.

In my template I then want to pass all the data from all 3 models because I would have to show the post data as well as looping through the comments to create a comments list and display all the attachments for the different comments.

```
class Post(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', blank=True, null=True, 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    content = models.TextField()


class Comment(BaseModel):
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    text = models.TextField()


class CommentAttachment(BaseModel):
    comment = models.ForeignKey('Comment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Should I fetch all data from `CommentAttachment` direction (meaning fetching all `CommentAttachments` where `comment__post__id` is the post id and then get all other data with `select_related`) or is there another way to start from the `Post` Model?

Comment: "fetch all data from CommentAttachment direction" is unclear to me. What have you tried so far ? It would help if you could paste your current view code or at least pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prefetch_related` or `select_related` in your query:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(user=some_user).prefetch_related(
    'comment_set', 'comment_set__commentattachment_set'
)
```

For example, after making a query as mentioned, the following command may retrieve all the comments for the first post in the queryset without making a SQL query:

```
posts.first().comment_set.all()
```

Comment: Thx for your quick answear seems like this should work just fine for me. But I've got one last question: How can I then get all CommentAttachments? I tried `posts.first().comment_set__commentattachment_set.all()` but that unfortunately doesn't work. Or is it even possible to loop through the `CommentAttachments` in the template then since it now should be attached to the `Comment`?

Comment: @Paul you can iterate over comments and retrieve attachments by a query like `my_comment.objects.commentattachment_set.all()`

Comment: first thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately I can't get it running. I tried to iterate over the comments as you mentioned but it doesn't work. I only get it running by iterating over the comments and then query the commentattachment but the problem then is that i have one additional query for each comment which would be far too much :/

Comment: Ok I got it to work with just `my_comment.commentattachment_set.all()` but would it also be possible to directly access it in the template? Because this way I would have to create a new dictionary attach all comments and their `commentattachments` to be able to display them in the template :/